# How to comment styles inside <style jsx> tag in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In CSS, you can comment out code using /* */.How to comment code inside `style jsx` in NextJS.I searched for this on the Internet but nothing was found.

```
<style jsx>{`
      table,th,td{
           border: 2px solid black;
      }

      #OOP{
        //height: 10vh;
        /*background-color: #28DE65;*/
  //Both of these comment styles doesn't work inside style jsx
      }
`}</style>
```

Comment: *"doesn't work"*. define it. ignored, or breaks the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS commenting works in `<style jsx>` in `next.js`. You might have missed/misconfigured something.

Demo

[image: Edit hello-world]

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix by `_`, it's not a comment but attribut are not interpreted :

```
<style jsx>{`
      table,th,td{
           border: 2px solid black;
      }

      #OOP{
        __height: 10vh;
        __background-color: #28DE65;
      }
`}</style>
```

Not elegant solution, but it works ;-)