# Configure how comment hotkey works in vs code with style jsx

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, css-in-js

I'm having issues when I try to `ctrl + /` to comment my style jsx code inside VS Code editor.

I found this question that relates, but never had a good answer. [How to comment styles inside <style jsx> tag in NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311645/how-to-comment-styles-inside-style-jsx-tag-in-nextjs)

The issue:

```
<style jsx>{`
    .myDashboard {
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 28px;
    }
`}</style>
```

In VS Code, when i use `ctrl + /` it tries to do a React JSX style comment

```
<style jsx>{`
    .myDashboard {
        {/* font-size: 13px; */}
        line-height: 28px;
    }
`}</style>
```

Resulting in this error

[image]

Is there an extension or setting I need to make VS Code play nice in my style jsx?
Thanks for your help!